# Error:table exists in the database

Tags: sap-ase, sap-iq, oracle-data-integrator

why is it that using exec() in SYBASE ASE while dropping a table if it exists eliminates the Error:Table exists in the database.  Why this error doesn't appear in Sybase IQ.

Answer (score 1):

Because Sybase/SAP ASE and Sybase/SAP IQ are completely different products. What works in one does not have to work in the other. You might as well ask why a statement in PL/SQL works in Oracle but does not work in MySQL.